# SQL Server Synonym without server name

Tags: sql-server, synonym

When I create a synonym in SQL Server 2014, both of the following syntaxes work for me:

```
CREATE SYNONYM MySynonym FOR [servername].[database].[dbo].[table]

CREATE SYNONYM MySynonym FOR [database].[dbo].[table]
```

Are there any downsides to not including the server name? Both correctly show the server name when viewing the synonym properties. The reason why I want to use the syntax without the server name is because it will not show up as a difference when using SSDT to compare database schemas. I know there is a setting to not compare Synonyms in SSDT but I want to compare them but just ignore the server name.

Comment: You should only use the server name when it is meant to reference a *different* instance than the one where the synonym exists. Specifying server in that case is no more useful than a query that references `SELECT ... FROM [this_server].[this_database].dbo.tablename;`

Comment: Thank you, this answers my question.

Comment: I've struggled with synonyms not working with Intellisense for a long time now.. only to recently realize it was due to providing a server name. If you leave the server name blank, then synonyms work in Intellisense. (in case anyone searches this problem and comes across this)